# Do CPU usage numbers/percentages (e.g. Task Manager) include memory I/O times?

Tags: memory, io, cpu

This is something I've always wondered but never looked up.

When an OS reports 100% CPU usage, does that necessarily mean that the bottleneck is calculations performed by the CPU, or does that include stall times, loading data from L1, L2, L3 and RAM?

If it does include stall times, is there a tool that allows to break the figure down into its components?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU usage reported by the OS includes time stalled waiting for memory accesses (as well as stalls from data dependencies on high latency computational operations like division).

I suspect that one could use performance counters to get a better handle on what is taking the time, but I am not familiar with the details of using performance monitoring counters.

Comment: Made community wiki because this is at best a partial answer.